# Partition on composite key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

In mysql can I have a composite primary key composed of an auto increment and another field? Also, please critique my “mysql partitioning” logic

To explain further->

I have a query about MySQL partition.
I have to partition a table in MySQL, It has one primary key id.
I have to partition by date field(non-primary,duplicate entries).
Since we cannot partition on duplicate entries, i have created a composite key->(id,date).
How can i create partition in this composite key?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

(This answer assumes InnoDB, not MyISAM.  There are differences in the  implementation of indexes that make some of my comments incorrect for MyISAM.)

In MySQL, a table's `PRIMARY KEY` can be composed of multiple fields, including an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

The only requirement in MySQL for `AUTO_INCREMENT` is that it be the *first* column in *some* index.  Let's look at this example of `Posts`, where there can be many posts for each user:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, post_id),
INDEX(post_id)
```

where `post_id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but you could benefit from "clustering" the data by `user_id`.  This clustering would make it more efficient to do queries like

```
SELECT ... FROM Posts
     WHERE user_id = 1234;
```

Back to your question...

The "partition key" does not have to be unique; so, I don't understant your "cannot partition on duplicate entries".

`INDEX(id, date)`, if you also have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, is essentially useless.  When looking up by id, the `PRIMARY KEY(id)` gives you perfect access; adding `date` to an index won't help.  When looking up by `date`, *but not `id`*, `(id, date)` is useless since only the "left" part of a composite index can be used.

Perhaps you are leading to a non-partitioned table with

```
PRIMARY KEY(date, id),
INDEX(id)
```

to make date ranges efficient?  (Note: partitioning won't help.)

Perhaps you will be doing

```
SELECT ... WHERE x = 123 AND date BETWEEN ...
```

In that case this is beneficial:

```
INDEX(x, date)
```

Only if you do this can we begin to discuss the utility of partitioning:

```
WHERE x    BETWEEN ...
  AND date BETWEEN ...
```

This needs a "two-dimensional" index, which sort of exists with `SPATIAL`.

See [*my discussion of partitioning*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) where I list only 4 use cases for partitioning.  It also links to an a discussion on how to use partitioning for 2D.

Bottom Line:  You *must not* discuss partitioning without having a clear picture of what queries it might help.  Provide them; then we can discuss further.